# Dial Position Gauge Chart Plotly R

Tags: r, svg, plotly

This question appears to have been asked a couple of times in one fashion or another, but I can't quite seem to find the correct answer. I'm trying to move the center dial on a `plotly` gauge chart. I'm using the demo that has been provided (https://plot.ly/r/gauge-charts/), and I'm also using guidance from this post ([How to rotate the dial in a gauge chart? Using python plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37454438/how-to-rotate-the-dial-in-a-gauge-chart-using-python-plotly)) - although it's `python` and not `r`.

I have absolutely zero experience with SVG- as I'm sure you can tell. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
h = 0.24
k = 0.5
r = 0.15

my_raw_value = 100
theta = my_raw_value * 180/300
theta = theta * pi / 180
x = h + r*cos(theta)
y = k + r*sin(theta)
path = paste0('M 0.235 0.5 L ' ,str(x) , '', str(y),' L 0.245 0.5 Z')

base_plot <- plot_ly(
  type = "pie",
  values = c(40, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
  labels = c("-", "0", "20", "40", "60", "80", "100"),
  rotation = 108,
  direction = "clockwise",
  hole = 0.4,
  textinfo = "label",
  textposition = "outside",
  hoverinfo = "none",
  domain = list(x = c(0, 0.48), y = c(0, 1)),
  marker = list(colors = c('rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(255, 255, 255)')),
  showlegend = FALSE
)

base_plot <- add_trace(
  base_plot,
  type = "pie",
  values = c(50, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10),
  labels = c("Error Log Level Meter", "Debug", "Info", "Warn", "Error", "Fatal"),
  rotation = 90,
  direction = "clockwise",
  hole = 0.3,
  textinfo = "label",
  textposition = "inside",
  hoverinfo = "none",
  domain = list(x = c(0, 0.48), y = c(0, 1)),
  marker = list(colors = c('rgb(255, 255, 255)', 'rgb(232,226,202)', 'rgb(226,210,172)', 'rgb(223,189,139)', 'rgb(223,162,103)', 'rgb(226,126,64)')),
  showlegend= FALSE
)

a <- list(
  showticklabels = FALSE,
  autotick = FALSE,
  showgrid = FALSE,
  zeroline = FALSE)

b <- list(
  xref = 'paper',
  yref = 'paper',
  x = 0.23,
  y = 0.45,
  showarrow = FALSE,
  text = '50')

base_chart <- layout(
  base_plot,
  shapes = list(
    list(
      type = 'path',
      path = path,
      xref = 'paper',
      yref = 'paper',
      fillcolor = 'rgba(44, 160, 101, 0.5)'
    )
  ),
  xaxis = a,
  yaxis = a,
  annotations = b
)
```

Why won't this path work? I hope it isn't an obvious answer that I'm ignorantly overlooking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in the definition of the `path` string.
Here is the right sintax:

```
path = paste('M 0.235 0.5 L' , x, y, 'L 0.245 0.5 Z')
```

[image]